# This site can’t provide a secure connection asp.net core from dotnet linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

I am currently developing an API using asp.net core 2.1. When I use the ide visual studio 2019 in windows I don't have problems running the project, but now  I am using manjaro linux and I compile by using dotnet console I have a error:
*This site can’t provide a secure connection
err_ssl_protocol_error*

[image]

Most of the solutions I've seen are made using the framework asp.net or changing options  the visual studio IDE, so I can not implement it in my project. I have tried adding:

```
.UseSetting("https_port", "5000")
```

inside program.cs but it didn't work

class program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    RunSeeding(host);//esta llamando el alimentador de la base de datos
    host.Run();
}

private static void RunSeeding(IWebHost host)
{
    var scopeFactory = host.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
    using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var seeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SeedDb>();
        seeder.SeedAsync().Wait();
    }
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSetting("https_port", "5000")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

configure.cs class

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();                


    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");


}
```

Comment: How are you running that? You said you build it through the console, but how are you running the application?

Comment: why not just host your application over http instead of https? It's only a localhost testing instance. The error is because the browser can't validate the SSL certificate being presented by the application (or perhaps, there was none presented, even). I would guess that VS2019 silently takes care of that behind the scenes when you run it in debug mode within the IDE, whereas the way you're running it in Linux does not.

Comment: Do you know How can I solve this problem? I use manjaro linux and version dotnet is 2.1. Editor code is visual studio code

Comment: Like I said, host your application over http instead of https. Technically it's more of a workaround than a solution...but equally I can't think why you need HTTPS for a local development environment. Just get rid of it

Comment: thanks, I understood your recommendation, I commented : `//app.UseHsts();` and `//.UseSetting("https_port", "5000")`. I'm working only http.

Answer (score 4):

Admittedly not using Linux, but in my case I was able to fix this on my asp.net core project by:

1. Open the project properties by right-clicking the project from the solution explorer and selecting properties
2. Open the Debug tab
3. Under "Web Server Settings", check "Enable SSL"

Now when I debug the application it automatically launches to the https URL.

Comment: But only if you've aligned it with a valid SSL certificate. Otherwise, same error.

Answer (score 2):

We have a known issue on which we're working currently for ASP.NET Core apps running in containers *on app service*. This issue is described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4135), as well as our plan to educate the community on how to work around this issue today *and* on how we plan on repairing it long-term. May not be related but wanted to drop it in here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working a localhost testing instance. I don't need to work with https so  disable https.

class program.css

```
//.UseSetting("https_port", "5000")
```

class startup.css

```
//app.UseHsts();
```

Comment: A simpler way to work around is to run the app (either `dotnet run` or any other options) with `--urls http://localhost:5000`, and that forces Kestrel to only listen at port 5000 and only process HTTP requests, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#endpoint-configuration If you do want to configure HTTPS properly, you can get started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.1?view=aspnetcore-2.2#https

Answer (score 0):

I am most likely late to the party but perhaps this might help someone else who will visit.
You can say the error is almost self explanatory, you are trying to reach the site using a non supported protocol. Please make sure you are using the correct protocol i.e if your site is http then make sure the url typed on the browser is indeed http, example https://localhost:8000 vs http://localhost:8000, note the letter s difference in the URLs. I ran into such issues and changing to the correct protocol solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using vs Code . .net version 6.
Removing below line from launchSettings.json worked for me

> "sslPort": 44308 <-- Remove this.

I run the project with

> dotnet run --urls "http://localhost:5100"

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.net Core 6, go to:

> Project --> <> Properties --> Debug --> General --> Open
> debug launch profiles UL --> IIS Express --> untick the Use SSL
> option.
>
> Clean --> Recompile --> Publish

Make sure your using `http` and not `https`

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio 2022 ,
I had to navigate to ,
Project Properties-> Debug Tab -> Open Debug launch profile UI
[image]

IIS Express-> Use SSL
[image]